# How to read parameters from .jenkins file to use in .java file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

In my Selenium and Java framework I want to give bearer token from .Jenkins file and use it in my .java file to execute my API.

Below is sample code of my .Jenkins file.

```
parameters {
   string name: 'envUnderTest', defaultValue: 'uat'
   string name: 'BearerToken', defaultValue: 'XXXXXX'
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Java file gets compiled and executed within the Jenkins pipeline, you could set up your Java code to accept [command line arguments](https://www.baeldung.com/java-command-line-arguments), then pass in the $BearerToken variable when the Java jar is being executed:

```
java -jar cli-example.jar $BearerToken
```